# Regex to parse SDDL

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python to parse out an SDDL using regex.  The SDDL is always in the form of 'type:some text' repeated up to 4 times.  The types can be either 'O', 'G', 'D', or 'S' followed by a colon. The 'some text' will be variable in length.

Here is a sample SDDL:

```
O:DAG:S-1-5-21-2021943911-1813009066-4215039422-1735D:(D;;0xf0007;;;AN)(D;;0xf0007;;;BG)S:NO_ACCESS_CONTROL
```

Here is what I have so far.  Two of the tuples are returned just fine, but the other two - ('G','S-1-5-21-2021943911-1813009066-4215039422-1735') and ('S','NO_ACCESS_CONTROL') are not.

```
import re

sddl="O:DAG:S-1-5-21-2021943911-1813009066-4215039422-1735D:(D;;0xf0007;;;AN)(D;;0xf0007;;;BG)S:NO_ACCESS_CONTROL"

matches = re.findall('(.):(.*?).:',sddl)

print matches

[('O', 'DA'), ('D', '(D;;0xf0007;;;AN)(D;;0xf0007;;;BG)')]
```

what I'd like to have returned is

```
[('O', 'DA'), ('G','S-1-5-21-2021943911-1813009066-4215039422-1735'), ('D', '(D;;0xf0007;;;AN)(D;;0xf0007;;;BG)'),('S','NO_ACCESS_CONTROL')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
(.):(.*?)(?=.:|$)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(.):(.*?)(?=.:|$)', sddl)
[('O', 'DA'), ('G', 'S-1-5-21-2021943911-1813009066-4215039422-1735'), ('D', '(D;;0xf0007;;;AN)(D;;0xf0007;;;BG)'), ('S', 'NO_ACCESS_CONTROL')]
```

This regex starts out the same way as yours, but instead of including the `.:` at the end as a part of the match, a lookahead is used.  This is necessary because `re.findall()` will not return overlapping matches, so you need each match to stop before the next match begins.

The lookahead `(?=.:|$)` essentially means "match only if the *next* characters are anything followed by a colon, or we are at the end of the string".

Comment: Beat me to it. Was just going to submit. Nice answer. Here's an explanation to the regex: http://regex101.com/r/uI4qX0

Comment: @Lindrian - Thanks for the link, haven't used regex101.com before, looks like a great tool!

Comment: You could even require the SDDL type to be one of O, G, D, S: [`([OGDS]):(.*?)(?=[OGDS]:|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/uI4qX0/2)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using regex isn't the best solution to this problem. Really, all you want to do is split across the colons and then do some transformations on the resulting list.

```
chunks = sddl.split(':')
pairs = [(chunks[i][-1], chunks[i+1][:-1] \
                             if i < (len(chunks) - 2) \
                             else chunks[i+1]) 
               for i in range(0, len(chunks) - 1)]
```